# Using 'cp' in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

Why doesn't this script work? It always opens the default directory where the script sits in, can't open new ones

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "choose a directory: " map
list=$( ls )
for item in $list; do
    echo $item
    read -p "Make copy? " ans

    if [ $ans = "yes" ]; then        
        cp $item > mkdir $map+copy
    fi
done
echo "Done"
```

Comment: Run the script through `shellcheck.net` and fix the errors it tells you about. (1) cp does not deal with redirects. (2) `+` is not a shell operator to concatenate strings. (3) `mkdir` runs on its own command line, and only needs to be run once (at most) because you only specify it once. (4) `ls` is not suitable for subsequent processing as it deals badly with spaces, special characters, and directories

Comment: Does this answer your question? [School task, bash scripting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643273/school-task-bash-scripting) ---- This is a direct copy of your earlier question. Please either delete the old or this one and update the other appropriately. As for now one cannot tell what you are aiming for.

Comment: This line `cp $item > mkdir $map+copy` attempts to copy `$item` to `$map+copy`, writing any output of the `cp` command to file `mkdir`. I don't think this is your intention. I can guess what your script is supposed to accomplish, but to avoid misunderstandings and incorrect assumptions, please tell us what the desired result is.

Comment: Expanding on @ berndbausch comment, change it to "cp ./$item $map" - map is a directory. And you should test that the target directory of the copy exists, i.e., $map. And you need the ./$item since the files probably arn't in your $PATH. Further, if you want people to type "yes" - then you need to tell them to type "yes" or modity the test to include "y".

Comment: I suggest that you try to manually run the commands that you're trying to script.  If you cannot run it manually, it's not going to work in the script either.  You need to understand what you're trying to accomplish and what sequence of commands will do what you're trying to accomplish before you start writing a script to do it.

Comment: If you've run this it will have given you errors. You haven't even mentioned these. Fix them, or if you're stuck ask about them. Even if someone here wrote your homework for you, what would that gain you, really? You won't have learned anything useful. Help you? Yes, certainly. Do your homework for you? Not really

Comment: @David, oops, I didn't realize this was connected to the earlier question.

Comment: @CinaedSimson: You're right that putting `./` before `$item` is a good idea, but you've got the wrong reason — it has nothing to do with $PATH.  Also, rather than saying "cp ./$item $map", you should say ```cp "./$item" "$map"``` (putting the variables in quotes).

Answer (score 1):

```
cp $item > mkdir $map+copy
```

Ok, so, `>` redirects the output of a command, the part that's printed (usually to your terminal). E.g. `ls` outputs a list of files, so `ls > list.txt` would output that list to `list.txt` instead. But e.g. `cp foo bar` explicitly opens the files `foo` and `bar`, but doesn't output anything to the terminal.

Thus, the redirection here, gives you an empty file called `mkdir`, but the rest of the command `cp $list $map+copy` would copy the file named by `$list` to whatever `$map+copy` expands to (the contents of the variable `$map` and the fixed string `+copy`, concatenated together).

On the other hand, `cat foo` would open `foo` and print it out, and you could use `cat foo > bar` to direct that printout to a file called `bar`. Pretty much the same as doing `cp foo bar`, actually, except that `cp` has options to like `-a` and `-p` to  also copy the owner and permission information.

And, in the shell, you can concatenate strings by just sticking them next to each other (without any whitespace in between). So, if you set the variables `x=foo y=bar`, all of these print `foobar`:

```
echo foobar
echo "foo""bar"
echo "$x$y"
echo "foo$y"
echo "${x}bar"
```

Which means that you can just do `"${map}copy"` or `"$map""copy"` to concatenate the two parts.

You do need to run `mkdir` separately from `cp`, though, so if `$map` contains `foobar`, and `$item` is `hello.txt`, this would create a directory `foobarcopy`, and copy `hello.txt` to that directory:

```
mkdir -p "${map}copy"
cp "$item" "${map}copy"
```

(`-p` tells `mkdir` not to error if the directory already exists.)

See:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

for issues wrt. (not) double-quoting the variables.

---

Also, instead of:

```
list=$( ls )
for item in $list; do
```

You can have the shell produce a list of filenames without calling `ls`:

```
for item in ./*; do
```

See:

- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: _Thus, with the redirection here, you just get an empty file called `mkdir`._  I think here, you'd both an empty file called `mkdir` and a copy of the source file in `$map+copy` (i.e., the same behavior as `cp $item $map+copy > mkdir`).

Comment: @AndyDalton, yes, bad phrasing on my part

Comment: (1) Also, of course, `"foo"bar` and `"$x"bar`, and hence `"$map"copy`.  (2) Of course `mkdir -p` has an additional benefit, if the user enters something like ```a/b/c``` for `map`.